# MRA + MDA for Thunderbird 24

Tags: email, thunderbird, procmail, fetchmail

I'm looking for a combination of MRA and MDA for Thunderbird to fulfill the task "Mirror mails from AOL account locally (mirror as in retrieve and store in a standardized format (maildir, mbox or database)) and display and operate on them (IMAP ops, delete, move, etc.) in Thunderbird 24 (TB) as they were in the AOL account (logical) AND save the setup of a mail server".

I'm stuck with the following issues:

- MRA deliver to SMTP (this would require a mail server to be set up to make delivery accessible for TB)
- MRA + MDA (checked getmail and fetchmail + procmail) deliver to directories in standardized formats, like maildir or mbox, or database which is not usable for Thunderbird (no sure sure about this, please prove me wrong)

Am I missing something? Can I get over this without setting up a mail server?

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird (at least for unix-like operating systems) does support Unix mailboxes. Look for `movemail` type of the mail account in the account configuration page.